# ResultSet object reaches the end after one iteration

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to read all records in a table from a database, and do some processing using those data. Following is the code that I use.

```
package differences;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class ConformancePercentageChecking {

    private final String dbDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private Connection connection = null;
    private final String serverName = "localhost";
    private final String mydatabase = "google";
    private final String username = "root";//kh hoseinpur
    private final String password = "123";
    private final String extrainfo = "?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
    int numberOfInsertedIDs = 0;

    public void findConformances() {
        try {
            try {
                Class.forName(dbDriver);//a call to forname("X") causes the class named X to be initialized
                String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName + "/" + mydatabase + extrainfo;
                if (connection == null) {
                    connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "database");
            }

            String query1, query2, query3, query4, query5, query6, testSuite, id;
            PreparedStatement statement1, statement2, statement3, statement4, statement5, statement6;
            query1 = "drop table PresConformance;";
            query2 = "drop table PostConformance;";
            statement1 = connection.prepareStatement(query1);
            statement2 = connection.prepareStatement(query2);
            statement1.executeUpdate();
            statement2.executeUpdate();
            query1 = "CREATE TABLE PresConformance(testSuite Text, conformance numeric(10), depthDifference numeric(10),pathLength numeric(10));";
            query2 = "CREATE TABLE PostConformance(testSuite Text, conformance numeric(10), depthDifference numeric(10),pathLength numeric(10));";
            query3 = "SELECT * FROM presDifference;";
            query4 = "SELECT * FROM presdifference;";
            query5 = "insert into PresConformance values(?,?,?,?);";
            query6 = "insert into PostConformance values(?,?,?,?);";
            statement1 = connection.prepareStatement(query1);
            statement2 = connection.prepareStatement(query2);
            statement3 = connection.prepareStatement(query3);
            statement4 = connection.prepareStatement(query4);
            statement5 = connection.prepareStatement(query5);
            statement6 = connection.prepareStatement(query6);
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

            statement1.executeUpdate();
            statement2.executeUpdate();

            ResultSet r1, r2, r3, r4;
            r1 = statement3.executeQuery();
            System.out.println("***1");
            r2 = statement4.executeQuery();
            System.out.println("***2");

            int idCount = 0, depthDifference = 0, totalNumberOfExecutions = 0, testSuitesCounts = 0, difference = 0, pathLength = 0;
            float conformancePercentage = 0, sumOfconformancePercentage = 0;
            r3 = r1;
            r4 = r2;
            while (r1.next()) {
                testSuitesCounts = 0;
                sumOfconformancePercentage = 0;
                testSuite = r1.getString("testSuite");
                id = null;
                id = map.get(testSuite);
                if (id == null) {
                    idCount++;
                    map.put(Integer.toString(idCount), testSuite);
                    r3.absolute(r1.getRow());
                    r3.previous();
                    while (r3.next()) {
                        if (testSuite.equals(r3.getString("testSuite"))) {
                            System.out.println(testSuite + " equal");
                            totalNumberOfExecutions = r3.getInt("totalNumberOfExecutions");
                            difference = r3.getInt("difference");
                            conformancePercentage = (1 - ((float) difference / totalNumberOfExecutions)) * 100;
                            if (testSuitesCounts == 0) {
                                String[] testSuite1, testSuite2, testSuite3;
                                testSuite1 = testSuite.split("_");
                                testSuite2 = testSuite1[0].split("/");
                                testSuite3 = testSuite1[1].split("/");
                                depthDifference = Math.abs(testSuite2.length - 1) - testSuite3.length;
                                pathLength = (testSuite2.length - 1) + testSuite3.length;
                            }
                            testSuitesCounts++;
                            sumOfconformancePercentage += conformancePercentage;
                        }
                    }
                    statement5.setString(1, testSuite);
                    statement5.setFloat(2, (sumOfconformancePercentage / testSuitesCounts));
                    statement5.setInt(3, depthDifference);
                    statement5.setInt(4, pathLength);
                    statement5.executeUpdate();
                }
                System.out.println(r1.getRow());
            }

            System.out.println("Pres Finished*****************************************");
            idCount = 0;
            map = new HashMap<>();
            while (r2.next()) {
                testSuitesCounts = 0;
                sumOfconformancePercentage = 0;
                testSuite = r2.getString("testSuite");
                id = null;
                id = map.get(testSuite);
                if (id == null) {
                    idCount++;
                    map.put(Integer.toString(idCount), testSuite);
                    r4.absolute(r2.getRow());
                    r4.previous();
                    while (r4.next()) {
                        if (testSuite.equals(r4.getString("testSuite"))) {
                            System.out.println(testSuite + " equal");
                            totalNumberOfExecutions = r4.getInt("totalNumberOfExecutions");
                            difference = r4.getInt("difference");
                            conformancePercentage = (1 - ((float) difference / totalNumberOfExecutions)) * 100;
                            if (testSuitesCounts == 0) {
                                String[] testSuite1, testSuite2, testSuite3;
                                testSuite1 = testSuite.split("_");
                                testSuite2 = testSuite1[0].split("/");
                                testSuite3 = testSuite1[1].split("/");
                                depthDifference = Math.abs(testSuite2.length - 1) - testSuite3.length;
                                pathLength = (testSuite2.length - 1) + testSuite3.length;
                            }
                            testSuitesCounts++;
                            sumOfconformancePercentage += conformancePercentage;
                        }
                    }
                    statement6.setString(1, testSuite);
                    statement6.setFloat(2, (sumOfconformancePercentage / testSuitesCounts));
                    statement6.setInt(3, depthDifference);
                    statement6.setInt(4, pathLength);
                    statement6.executeUpdate();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Post Finished*****************************************");

            System.out.println("Finished Inserting to DB");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DifferencesPresPost.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem, is that for both ResultSet objects r1 and r3, which contain tables' records, it just iterates once, and then reaches the end of the ResultSet objects.

I tried to count number of records in both ResultSet objects before each while loop, and it correctly prints the number of recoreds, but when it enters in these while loops, it works for only first row of each ResultSet objects. 
Can any body help me to find out the result of this problem?

Comment: Do you have any exceptions in your log?

Comment: Your title doesn't match your problem; your result set does **not** become null. And please, reduce your code to the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem (a [mcve])

Comment: where do you set up presDifference & presdifference

Comment: No. I don't receive any exceptions.

Comment: Those tables are created and filled up in another similar class.

Comment: Which loop are you talking about? `while (r1.next())` or `while (r3.next())`? Also `r3` is pointing to the same ResultSet as `r1` so when inner loop for `r3` is done both `r1` and `r3` are pointing to the ResultSet with all records processed.

Comment: while (r1.next()) loop. Do you mean that r1 and r3 are associated and when r3 reaches the end, r1 reaches the end as well?

Comment: @zari, yes, they are both pointing to the same `ResultSet` object

Comment: @Ivan Thanks a lot. It solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I believe by default your resultsets are TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY. You need to specify TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE when preparing your prepared statements. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you provide the minimal code to reproduce your problem?

Comment: The last comment by Ivan helped. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you think using `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` would solve this problem? I can't think of any reason why it would help for the problem as described.